# The type JoinMessages must implement the inherited abstract method CommandExecutor.onCommand(CommandSender, Command, String, String[])

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

So I'm trying to make a Minecraft Plugin at the moment, and I have made my code, most of it is perfect, however for some reason I'm getting the error message (the title) from Eclipse once it's written.

Code found here: https://paste.helpch.at/ucadukekew.java

I'm also getting an error in my Main.java file. "Cannot instantiate the type JoinMessages" next to the code:

```
this.getCommand("joinmessages").setExecutor(new JoinMessages(this));
```

Is anyone able to help me get this fixed please? Feel free to let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong `Command`. You're using `com.mojang.brigadier.Command` (because of your `import`), but you should be using `org.bukkit.command.Command`.

Comment: Thank you. I actually had a few issues which I managed to fix as well, appreciate your help!